# why this SELECT * FROM database wont work?

Tags: php, mysql

```
include "connect.php";

$deck = addslashes($_GET['deck']);
$side = addslashes($_GET['side']);
$type = addslashes($_GET['type']);
$by = addslashes($_GET['creator']);
$name = addslashes($_GET['name']);

$table = "deck";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = '$name' AND by = '$by'");
if(!$result){
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO $table (deck, side, name, type, by) VALUES ('$deck', '$side', '$name', '$type', '$by')";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
}
```

the insert into never gets inserted, my database is like

```
id int(11) autoincrement
deck varchar(900)
side varchar(900)
type varchar(900)
by varchar(900)
name varchar(900)
```

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors? `mysql_error()` is your friend. Get to know it

Comment: **WARNING:** Do not use `addslashes()` to escape your strings; it is insufficient and will leave you with security holes. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead. Better yet, stop using the obsolete `mysql_xxx()` functions entirely, and switch to a better DP API like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which will allow you to use modern techniques like parameterised queries.

Comment: If the record already exists that won't make the SELECT query crash as your code assumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by is reserved keyword.

use like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = '$name' AND `by` = '$by'");
```

Comment: You would have known this was the issue if you actually checked for errors after a query. Functions offere return codes for a reason, if they return something on failure, check that they worked